# EF reverse engineer code first doesn't work in VS 2015

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed EF Power tools in VS 2015 and i have entity framework nuget package version 6.1.3 and when i try to use reverse engineer code first, the tool doesn't work at all.

The tool creates the context class only with no table classes or mapping folder as it was working in VS 2013.

Any fix or workaround for this bug ?

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the built-in EDM Wizard (Add New ADO.NET Entity data Model) to generate Code First from Database code. You could also consider using the "EF Reverse POCO Template" available on the VS gallery (in Tools/Extensions and Updates)

Comment: I tried the ADO.NET data model from db and still VS is not adding any existing tables in the model while generation or after creating the mode. it is so frustrating.

Comment: Does your tables have primary keys?

Comment: yes. i do have a primary key in my table i am adding to the model.

Comment: Actually i found out that my VS 2015 was acting weird after latest updates which i fixed and now everything is working properly including generating schemas/classes in EF.

Comment: So my reply answered your question?

Comment: @Mostafa in which way did you fix your issue ?